# Getting a program to run certain functions every hour in MFC C++

Tags: c++, mfc

I am trying to create a program that runs certain functions every hour in mfc c++.

I couldn't find any good tutorial outside on how to do this as I am still in the learning process and trying to expand my knowledge on this.

Just a little something so it wouldn't seem that I am just asking empty questions, so far I created a program that reads value from an .INI file and stored it in the global variables within the program. I've manage to make it run indefinitely in the System Tray and my plan is to ultimately parse some text from a .txt file into a .csv file every hour.

So to reiterate, can anyone explain to me the logic and a rough method on how to do it? For my learning process, i would just like to know how i can show

```
MessageBox("Hello");
```

every 1 minute or so just for my own understanding.

Comment: For a start [look at SetTimer](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/49313fdf.aspx) and see how you get on.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

As you're using `MFC` then I'm supposing you're using Windows as your OS.

The *normal* way of approaching this is to use the Task Scheduler in Windows to schedule the running of your program at the desired intervals. (You can use the Task Scheduler to configure command line arguments too).

I'd be reluctant to use timers in the application itself as I'd question the stability of such an approach.

Comment: Why would you be reluctant to use timers? If you need external triggers, when your application isn't running the task scheduler is great. But if your application is running and needs to perform a periodic activity then timers are the right tool.

Comment: Also, it depends on what the OP means by 'every hour'.  Could be 'every instance that the wall time minutes goes from 59 to 0', or 'roughly every 60 minutes'.

Comment: exactly what nik bougalis said. I have to use timer as the program has to be on 24/7. the text that it is going to parse would be from a .txt file that is being updated continously throughout the day.

Martin : what i mean by every hour is that my program will run at say 1am, 2am, 3am, 4am, 5am and so on indefinitely

Comment: In which case I'd *certainly* use the task scheduler for this. But appreciate it's personal opinion.

Comment: I truly thank you for the suggestion, I myself had thought of using the task scheduler but it would means i wont be learning about timers which is my main goal at this point to expand my knowledge and improve myself in terms of MFC programming.

Answer (score 0):

Use a Windows timer. Get the wall-time and calculate how many ms are left until the next XX:00.  Set the timer interval to, (say), half that.  In the timer handler, repeat that calcuation and timer-set until the time remaining is less than 1000 ms and then set the timer to the remaining interval.  Next time it fires, perform your operation and then set the timer for the next hour.

You can 'creep up' on the hour quite accurately in such a manner.